# Updating Azure SBNotificationHub tags after initial registration

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, azure-notificationhub

I have a Xamarin Forms App which registers for notifications fine for iOS via the AppDelegate and the RegisteredForRemoteNotifications method. I have a tag I register here as well.

I was looking to have user settings to be able to update the tag registered. So as a test, I create a Dependency Service taking the Device Token and tag.

```
 public async void UpdateTags(string token, string tag)
        {
            NSData deviceToken = new NSData(token, NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.None);


            Hub = new SBNotificationHub(Constants.ListenConnectionString, Constants.NotificationHubName);

     

            string[] SubscriptionTags = { tag };

            var tags = new NSSet(SubscriptionTags.ToArray()); 

            Hub.UnregisterAll(deviceToken, (error) =>
            {
                if (error != null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Unable to call unregister {error}");

                    return;
                }

         

               
                Hub.RegisterNative(deviceToken, tags, (errorCallback) =>
                {
                    if (errorCallback != null)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine($"RegisterNativeAsync error: {errorCallback}");
                    }
                });

                var templateExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddDays(120).ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
                Hub.RegisterTemplate(deviceToken, "defaultTemplate", Constants.APNTemplateBody, templateExpiration, tags, (errorCallback) =>
                {
                    if (errorCallback != null)
                    {
                        if (errorCallback != null)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine($"RegisterTemplateAsync error: {errorCallback}");
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
           

        }
```

This method runs correctly and the hub referred to here has the updated tags but the app seems to hold on to the old tag.

Do I need to refer to the original Hub created in the RegisteredForRemoteNotifications method in AppDelegate.cs?

Or is this the wrong approach? Long story short I need to update tags created via the RegisteredForRemoteNotifications method in AppDelegate.cs on app load.

Thank you!

Comment: like this said https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63485735/xamarin-forms-ios-saving-a-user-tag-in-azure-notification-hubs-works-in-appdel  Basically SBNotificationHub method overloads like UnregisterAll and RegisterTemplate with the callback signature do not work when you use them off the main thread

Comment: try https://github.com/azure/azure-notificationhubs-xamarin instead